# Do component JSX elements have to sit next to each other?

Tags: react-native

Imagine some reusable components consisting of `TextInput`s (*for a blog title*) and `CheckBoxe`s (*For example to capitalize all characters of the paired TextInput*). Now, I want every `TextInput`-`CheckBox` pair to be 100% inside one functional component, and **not** in two different components (*eg for re-usability purposes*). **So Initially it would be something like this:**

```
[TextInput1_blogTitle]
()CheckBox1

[TextInput2_AuthorName]
()CheckBox2

[TextInput3_SourceName]
()CheckBox3
```

The **problem** is, if both the `TextInput` and the `CheckBox` are in the same component, they will also appear **next to each other** on the screen (*one on top of the other*), but there are also other `checkbox`es and `TextInput`s from other components on the screen, and I want all the `TextInput`s and all the `CheckBox`es to be packed together and shown in their own sections of the screen. So this is **what I need**:

```
[TextInput1_blogTitle]
[TextInput2_AuthorName]
[TextInput3_SourceName]

()CheckBox1
()CheckBox2
()CheckBox3
```

Is there a way that every component **sends part of its JSX element to a different section of the screen**? How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can do something using ```CSS```. But as a general answer in my opinion: it seems impossible to do this in ```REACT``` way. (without manual DOM ...).